# jQuery Replace character and symbol in string in each div , comma by € and € by nothing

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, replace, split

so here is the scenario:
I have a bunch of spans with  a class of " price " like that : 12,99€

I needed to split the cents after the coma so I could style it with css -> that's done , cents got its own class " cents "

Now I'm trying to replace the coma "," by the € euro symbol, and remove the € symbol at the end 'replace it with nothing, empty)

I hope it makes sense, here is an example...:

How it is now: 12,99€
and
What I need: 12€99

My code right now:

```
<!-- the html part CANNOT BE MODIFIED -->
<span class="price">29,49€</span>

<script>
jQuery(".price").each(function() {
var newText = jQuery(this).text().split(",").join("</span>,<sup class='cents'>");
newText = "<span class='euros'>" + newText + "</sup>";
jQuery(this).html(newText);
});

// Tryed to replace euro symbol by nothing but doesn't work //
var value = jQuery(".cents").val()+"";
value.replace("€", "");
var val = jQuery(".cents").val();
</script>
```

I would definitely appreciate if someone could help me out here since I really want to learn how to achieve this. It doesn't look too complicated but can't make it work which is frustating.

Comment: `.val()` is for form elements, you should use `.text()` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using the following instead:

```
$(".price").html(function(i, val) {
    val = val.split(",");
    return "<span class='euros'>" + val[0] + "</span>" + "€" +
        "<sup class='cents'>" + val[1].replace("€", "") + "</sup>";
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/8da54/11/

Comment: Thanks, good try for making it shorter but it seem to output the html tags aswell ? Look here: http://jsfiddle.net/8da54/10/

Comment: When you return string with html to `text` it will be displayed as string.

Comment: @mlclm Yeah, I forgot to change `text()` to `html()`. Now it should work perfectly, check the DEMO.

Comment: Very nice indeed VisioN thanks for sharing your solution, I will study the slice function to know how to use it. Thanks again!

Comment: *I forgot to change `text()` to `html()` when copypasting Esailija's answer and jsfiddle* :P

Comment: @Esailija Right, your fiddle perfectly supplemented my answer ;P

Comment: I get value[1] is undefined for some reason ?

Comment: my bad , code is working perfectly well. Thanks again! All good. :)

Answer (score 3):

```
$(".price").text( function(i, oldtext){
    return oldtext.replace("€","").replace(",","€")
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8da54/9/

Comment: Nice this technique also worked. Thanks for contributing Esailija!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `replace`, you can use `slice` or `substr`.

```
$(".price").html(function(i, oldVal) {
    var value = oldVal.split(",");
    return "<span class='euros'>" + value[0] + "€</span>" +
        "<sup class='cents'>" + value[1].slice(0, -1) + "</sup>";
});
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2hpVt/1/)

Comment: Superb it's working perfectly. Thank you very much. I will learn from you.